# Issue using not exist in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

`Not exist` is not working.

I have a query which is fetching 10k rows... now there are 237 rows which I do not want to be retrieved in my final result but when I am using not exist it is fetching the same no. of rows that is 10k I have used the following query:

```
Select bu_name,
       person_num, 
       name, 
       f_config_id, 
       ass_the 
from   x_asig_table
where  not exist ((select 1
                   from    
                       (select XXH.x_asig_table.*,
                               count(*) over (partition by bu_name, person_num, name) as c
                        from XXH.x_asig_table) t
                   where c > 1);
```

Comment: Why are you using "select 1", what kind of value do you want to compare in you "not exist" statement?

Comment: After some quick code formatting - there appears to be an unmatched opening bracket; is that the issue? Otherwise, can you post deatils of the error you are having.

Comment: Are `x_asig_table` and `XXH.x_asig_table` the same table or are they in two difference schemas?

Answer (score 0):

The sub-query is not correlated with the main query, i.e. it doesn't matter what row you look at in the main query, the subquery will always give you the same result. So either you get all rows or none. It is not possible with this query to get some rows and others not.

Add criteria to your subquery that relates it to the main query to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect back to the outer query. Something like this (also simplified your query, untested, but should work):

```
Select bu_name,
       person_num, 
       name, 
       f_config_id, 
       ass_the 
from   x_asig_table X
where  not exist (
                     SELECT      NULL
                     FROM        x_asig_table Y
                     GROUP BY    bu_name,person_num, name
                     WHERE       X.bu_name = Y.bu_name
                            AND  X.person_num = Y.person_num
                            AND  X.name = Y.name
                     HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to find only those rows where there is a single row per combination of `bu_name`, `person_num` and `name` (although the question is rather unclear what your intents are). If so, then you can do it without using `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT bu_name,
       person_num, 
       name, 
       f_config_id, 
       ass_the
FROM   (
  SELECT bu_name,
         person_num, 
         name, 
         f_config_id, 
         ass_the,
         COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY bu_name, person_num, name ) AS cnt
  FROM   x_asig_table
)
WHERE  cnt = 1;
```